# Chrome blurs text at a net rotation of 0, but I can't replicate it out of environment

Tags: css, google-chrome, rotation, chromium, blink

It's well known that Chrome has trouble displaying text at a net rotation without blurring it. However, at a net 0 rotation (e.g. rotating a container element +1deg and the text itself or another container -1deg) this shouldn't be the case, as the offset is 0. And indeed, in the sample I've cooked up here, if you look at it in Chrome, you should see that the text isn't blurred:

```css
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(46deg, #fff, #f2f2f2, #e8e8e8);
  background-size: 600% 600%;
  animation: backgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
  max-width: 85%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5%;
  padding: 5vw;
  transform: rotate(-.5deg);
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.sheet {
  transform: rotate(0.5deg);
  font-size: 16px;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #e43624, #e74b3b, #ea6052);
  animation: backgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
  background-size: 600% 600%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Sarala;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sarala%7CGochi+Hand" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sheet">
      <section>
        <p>
          This is a long block of text with the rotation system. Yay. Let's see if this works
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now you might think that's a lot of styles which are beside the point, and you'd be right - because the trouble is, this exact same situation doesn't work on my portfolio website. If you browse to https://mashedkeyboard.me/ in Chrome, you'll find that the text is ever-so-slightly blurred still, despite the entire setup having been replicated in the sample above.

Initially, I thought this must have been an issue with some of the surrounding styles, which is why I put all the container styles into the sample here. But no joy - I still can't replicate the issue elsewhere.

The only thing which I can do to fix the issue is activate the `:hover` on the profile image on the side of the site, which appears in the Chrome Layer Debugger as flattening the entire page to a single layer for the duration of the rotation for some reason - but this isn't possible to apply permanently.

None of these issues affect Firefox or Edge at all; both render the text smoothly with no issues.

I'm a bit stumped at this point. If anyone has any ideas on 1) why this is happening in the first instance, or 2) how it might be possible to get around it, they'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who searches this issue up for whatever reason, it turns out it's a Blink compositing bug. It's being [actively worked on at the moment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=919294).